# TypeScript: narrowing type of object field

Tags: typescript

I got and deeply nested object and function that "unwraps" it layer by layer. But when last "layer" gets optional TypeScript somehow looses track of its type.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMCGAXBtrqfEVqVbsEQETQBOdJ1AvgDStXwCMRAcj4Dunbnn4wBEkW0yYoATwAOAUxgARVauUB5JKhhK1IAGZwkCleoByeRoxAB3fYgA8umKoAeUVWAATCAxOGABpL19-IJgAa1VFMxhdAD5DXQBtMIBdAG55UEhYAHNVKC0dADU8ABtDN25PHz9A4Iq9JC5SMN5Ilpj4xPN21y7cMIAmPujgwaS7B2dXDw5w3hSxnDCAZmnWuIT5+0cXJDcFk+XdDh6N8ImUzDSACm4QImvuWMkezbiJoiTP6xbYAfkB20wAEpUGlKLhGGUAK6MMBxXaguAZb7ZbETXEg7IwIggbG8An4zByTAAehpMERECRNSgRCYAEswMUYAAfDAwWgwDlc3IwNgwTnQVR4AJwczC4qYQrQBmqJkswylcraZTVGrPBCIVbSATG+CmqTAARQoA)

I expect the type of `result` to be `string` not `string | { c: string }` with the following code:

Is it bug or expected behavior?

```js
const obj = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: "str"
        },
        b1: 'b1'
    },
    a1: 'a1'
}

type DeepObj = typeof obj
type NarrowObj<O extends {}, K extends keyof O> = O[K];

const getDeepVal = <
    O extends DeepObj,
    K1 extends keyof DeepObj,
    K2 extends keyof NarrowObj<O, K1>,
    K3 extends keyof NarrowObj<NarrowObj<O,K1>, K2>
> (
    o: O,
    k1: K1,
    k2: K2,
    k3?: K3
) => {
    return k3 ? o[k1][k2][k3] : o[k1][k2]
}

// result: string | { c: string; } instead of string
const result = getDeepVal(obj, 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected behavior: the return type of `getDeepVal` is `O[K1][K2] | O[K1][K2][K3]`.  The compiler does not synthesize a conditional type that checks if `K3` is defined and narrows the return type accordingly.  Actually, even `getDeepVal(obj, 'a', 'b')` will infer `'c'` for `K3`, so even if `k3` is `undefined`, `K3` will not be.  The solution here would be to change the signature to detect whether the value is undefined or not and explicitly make our own conditional type to represent it.  Here's a possibility:

```
const getDeepVal = <
    O extends DeepObj,
    K1 extends keyof O,
    K2 extends keyof O[K1],
    K3R extends [(keyof O[K1][K2])?]
>(
    o: O,
    k1: K1,
    k2: K2,
    ...[k3]: K3R
) => {
    return (k3 ? o[k1][k2][k3!] : o[k1][k2]) as
        K3R[0] extends infer K3 ? (
            K3 extends keyof O[K1][K2] ? O[K1][K2][K3] : O[K1][K2]
        ) : never;
}
```

In the above, we've replaced the `k3` parameter and `K3` type, with a `[k3]` rest parameter and a `K3R` tuple type ([tuple types can represent the type of rest parameters in TS3.0+](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types)).  The `K3R` tuple has a single [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) element, representing the fact that `k3` is an optional parameter.  This rest-parameter type juggling is necessary for the compiler to recognize that when `k3` is left out, the type of `K3R[0]` will be `undefined`.  If you do it the straightforward way you were doing, leaving out `k3` will cause `K3` to be inferred as `keyof O[K1][K2]` and *not* `undefined`, and we'll have nothing the compiler can use to distinguish `k3` being present from it being absent.

Anyway the return type takes the first element of the rest tuple and stores it in `K3`, and then checks to see if `K3` is actually a key type of `O[K1][K2]`.  If so, the return type is `O[K1][K2][K3]`; otherwise it is `O[K1][K2]`.  Now your calls should behave as you expect:

```
const resultTwoLevels = getDeepVal(obj, 'a', 'b') // { c: string; }
const resultThreeLevels = getDeepVal(obj, 'a', 'b', 'c') // string
const resultNotSure = getDeepVal(obj, 'a', 'b',
    Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'c' : void 0); // string | { c: string; }
```

Looks good.

---

Note that this is quite a complicated signature with conditional types.  The other way to deal with this would be to use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to represent the `k3`-present and `k3`-absent behavior separately.  Like this:

```
// Call signatures
function getDeepVal<O extends DeepObj, K1 extends keyof O, K2 extends keyof O[K1]>(
    o: O, k1: K1, k2: K2
): O[K1][K2];
function getDeepVal<
    O extends DeepObj, K1 extends keyof O, K2 extends keyof O[K1],
    K3 extends keyof O[K1][K2]>(o: O, k1: K1, k2: K2, k3: K3): O[K1][K2][K3];
// the next one might not be needed if you never intend to call both at once
// as in "resultNotSure"
function getDeepVal<
    O extends DeepObj, K1 extends keyof O, K2 extends keyof O[K1],
    K3 extends keyof O[K1][K2]>(o: O, k1: K1, k2: K2, k3?: K3): O[K1][K2][K3] | O[K1][K2];

// Implementation:
function getDeepVal<
    O extends DeepObj, K1 extends keyof O, K2 extends keyof O[K1],
    K3 extends keyof O[K1][K2]>(o: O, k1: K1, k2: K2, k3?: K3) {
    return k3 ? o[k1][k2][k3] : o[k1][k2]
}
```

That is more signatures but it behaves the same as the conditional type method, and it might make more sense to people reading it because it does less type juggling.  Let's make sure it works:

```
const resultTwoLevels = getDeepVal(obj, 'a', 'b') // { c: string; }
const resultThreeLevels = getDeepVal(obj, 'a', 'b', 'c') // string
const resultNotSure = getDeepVal(obj, 'a', 'b',
    Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'c' : void 0); // string | { c: string; }
```

Also good.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAsAKBnmAhgFwY77kzwla4V3AkBE0ATo2XTAL4A0Hd8AIwkA5EJH9ufWngLCYIuROxccOKAE8ADgFMYAER06tAeSSoYm3SABmcJDjAEAtjohaCwPQGFwAEwBLKADwAgAbUhkYUEhYAHMdKENjADVwiwAeSXITGB0ADygdMD8IAyNTJGlOGABpQTzC4tKYAGsdDVsYE2rOWoAmRqKSsvbOuxMAbXqAXV66WoBmACUh5rLJgAoxrqnZ6f6ZgEoAfhnJAD5N7PwQEh6bvFb5evmKVv6SAbfyADp-yatRYzL4rSRHVAXSI1FiJACuLDAMG2ixgJzggMEM0Bh0BiwAhDMYCQQJjsR9joQII8KEtlpMAAxEgrDFoBMA2HQsOqo9HXKI1chLNYjNodXbTLEHInovZSgbYpZE+6SxWHGnkCEkMA6ABuXIA3JJVNhJDFoDBYRA4WEoAAVADuIAAMnqdGEymgEkkKmkwpsEIgeAoCCJg2IRBCAPRRjDREisdlxA3cM3gC1Wm32gAWsJ0rv1Hos3uSWj9AaqIbDCng1ZEwEjMBjMETYDiadilrcWYAciAoABlBF6L2JUvlwPh0Ph2s-fAAWQIUGzvxYBBKIGcmwhGRgDN+AFY0QoG8SYLqQAE-Hujinm624jAAD5xhgtqAsJMpk04H-YJyuO4nh6CY+osGEIAEC0NCSM23jhBEEABHEThQMO1JRDYcJgMAwTgDAJa+uEGS5Cy6zlMYZhBnUDRkaKOwTMGAwii0DHdKqVw0nc3TBs8XyCLxnx1P04IqvsCpGph2G4SESKEakxE0qRTSiqWVFMbRKmseKjHCSxow6exsxzngwp0dp4xGfKhxXNxPRtC8AltEJ3xtIsoJHGJ1mKsCknkM2y56DqhRwDqMDOMh2awGA-aUEFRh+Do14BHYnRwjAOpgTA7KspYIDRAhlD9tmhCwOAXiwbGBBlOyMCMJmtp9oOw7sFJOF4XJY5EWEWQCvgymsmUamVvU+lipZ9nMeZBkTaqJk8mNbFymqMy2fcvGOYJXz9LxiwnB5XkrdMwLPlZK2SZVMAAJLOFoYQ6K4YBQEuslEJIWHtbJBFdQpPVKWNw3UaN03jbsTGDCDS1zTSZlaTNEriTZAbrQ5-FbcJu37TyEI0DC8KIm5x6ks85K4kCyoYiTOLnFEf7kOasANfaToFu6nrfT6v0VtRih1rW0axug8bvp+bbfh2Gbdradq5kYrNFqOnNluE3NTnzdYNgLItJhLjNS1ATVDrCxY-cr-qTlWM5hjSi7Lqu65+Ju24wLu+5Hui9YiGeF5Xjed6xg+p1C2+D7i6a4e-kAA)

Comment: Thank you, sir! I can't appreciate your answer enough. This rest args thing trick is marvelous.